# Eclipse: Green rectangle label on Class

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

What does the green thing seen on the upper-right side of class icon indicate?

I couldn't find anything on it after searching for `label` inside `Eclipse preferences`.

Comment: @eatSleepCode It's existing class, already added to the repository. The whole project is on repo, with "standard" labels, but just few classes are decorated that way.

Comment: I checked it with my code its on local but there is no green thing. I guess it shows your file is in sync with the file on repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen it, but a very (**very**) dirty and time loosing way to know would be to go to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations** and to select only one label decorations at a time to see which pluggin is making this green box appears and then check on this pluggin documentation.

Comment: Thanks, it was quite easy and fast. I'll add an answer to point exact source of that label.

Comment: And anyway... it's easier to not select one-at-a-time, but to do a binary search. Remove all labels, if that helped: remove only half, and check if it's gone or not... And continue till finding that one label ;)

Comment: You clearly deserve +1 for this comment it's better to think before acting stupidly, looks like I didn't do that for this one

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @T.Des answer, I was able to find the answer:

[image]

It comes from a plugin that I've recently installed, that greatly support unit-testing - [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: So you installed it without looking at the screenshots on the front page of the plugin?